# how can I change all wordpress media file url to custom cdn url?

Tags: functions, images, urls, media

any function can apply change all image URLs to CDN instead of modifying media.php in wp-includes folder
?

Comment: are you comfortable with wp-cli?

Comment: If you're using an existing CDN service there are very high chances that there is a plugin available for integration with WordPress. This allows for automatically rewriting all the URLs to a respective CDN URL. What CDN are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I did this by using [wp super cache](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-super-cache/). One thing that confused me was that you have to turn on the caching, even if all you want is the CDN rewriting.

I looked at a number of other CDN/rewriting plugins and nothing worked.

Answer (score 0):

You can place this in your `functions.php` file:

```php
add_filter('wp_get_attachment_url', 'replace_media_url');
function replace_media_url($url) {
    $custom_url = 'https://mybucket.nyc3.cdn.digitaloceanspaces.com';
    $path = 'uploads';// the path in the CDN
    
    // Check if the URL is a media URL
    if (strpos($url, 'wp-content/uploads') !== false) {
        // Replace the media URL with the custom URL
        $url = str_replace('wp-content/uploads', $path, $url);
        $url = str_replace(site_url(), $custom_url, $url);
    }
    return $url;
}
```

Every time your media is accessed, WordPress will return the CDN URL instead (even in the admin area).